# how to execute composer command

Tags: cmd, composer-php

I installed composer with installation file and I'm using Wamp server
that is in G:\wamp. then when I run in cmd  this command (G:\wamp\www\composer) it returns an error that composer is not recognized

Comment: It's easier to add the path in your `System Variables` and then you can call Composer from everywhere.

Comment: I added G:\wamp\www path but again CMD says composer is not recognized...

Comment: finally i installed from cmd and i set environment variable correctly and php composer.phar command in cmd now is working but again in cmd It's not working !!!!!!!